# How can I print the 1st and 2nd elements on a line, then 2nd and 3rd on the next line, then 3rd and 4th next line, and so on

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to print array elements 1st and 2nd in one line, then next line 2nd and 3rd elements, but I'm still stuck.

Input:

```
const arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
```

Output

```
10 - 20
20 - 30
30 - 40
40 - 50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i ++) {
  console.log(arr[i] + ' - ' + arr[i+1]);
}
```

but I'd recommend using the syntax

```
console.log(`${arr[i]} - ${arr[i+1]}`)
```